# Need ng-repeat filter to ignore any hyperlink string values when filtering view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I trying to filter an **ng-repeat** view of multiple item titles wrapped in hyperlinks but am getting results based on the Title and the URL string value.

How can I limit my filter to only the text of the Title and omit positives in the URL? E.g. If I search for "email" I would get results for items that have "email" in their title or text body but I would also get results that have "email" in their URL string.

```
<a href="http://google.com?q=email">Search Google for email</a><p>Blah blah blah</p>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<div ng-app="Home">
<div ng-controller="Details">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="searchBox">
                <input type="search" ng-model="search"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="SectionItem in Sections" ng-init="filterResult=[]" ng-hide="filterResult[$parent.$index].length <= 0">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div>
                        <h1>{{SectionItem.Title}}</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <!-- BEGIN: items belonging to this section -->                         
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                            <tr ng-repeat="item in (filterResult[$parent.$index] = (SectionItems | filter:search | filterByMatchingSection:SectionItem.Title)) ">
                                <td>

                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12" ng-show="item.Title != null">
                                                <a href="{{item.URL}}">{{item.Title}}</a>
                                                <p>
                                                    {{item.TextBody}}
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- END: items belonging to this section -->
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search.Title"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) you can use *a pattern object expression*. For your case this should work:

```
... | filter: { title: search } | ...
```

This will search only in the **title** property.